# An interesting problem about a "quasi ideal"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, rngs

Let R be an infinite ring without an unity. Let I ⊆ R satisfying: for any a,b ∈ I, r ∈ R, we have a+b ∈ I, ar ∈ I, ra ∈ I. Then there are two possibilities about I:
(1) I must be an ideal, i.e., for any a ∈ I, we have -a ∈ I;
(2) there exists b ∈ I such that -b ∉ I.
Which one is right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you believe that one of (1) and (2) has to be true in general? I mean, $I = R$ satisfies (1), but $I = 2\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \subseteq 2 \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies (2). Also notice the third possibility $I = \emptyset$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I think (1) and (2) has to be true in general because "I" is amost an ideal except satisfying "I" is an additional subgroup,i.e.a-b∈ I,that is to say：-b ∈ I.

Comment: On the other hand,I think your example may not be proper, since if we take 4  ∈I= 2Z≥0,-6 ∈2Z,then 4(-6)=-24∉ I,which is contradicted with the conditions. All above let us assume that I ≠ ∅.

Comment: Yes, my example was wrong. I shall think about this a bit more.

Comment: Correct me again if I am wrong, but what happens when multiplication in $R$ is constant $0$? It seems to me that every subset which is additively closed then satisfies your conditions but not all of them need to contain additive inverses.

Comment: Yeah,but it seems hard for me to find a  specific example.

Comment: What do you mean? You could just take any (infinite) abelian group $R$, for example $R = \mathbb{Z}$, and define a multiplication which is constant $0$. This gives you an (infinite) ring which is not unital. For $R = \mathbb{Z}$ with zero multiplication, the set $I = \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is closed under addition but not under additive inverses.

Comment: You are right! Thanks very much.